# How long do I have before the battery status changes from service recommended to replace now?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have an early-2015 MacBook Pro 13" whose battery status has changed from normal to 'service recommended' state. The cycle count is around 367 and the battery backup runs strong at around 4-5 hours. My understanding of the service recommended status is that the cells in the battery have begun deteriorating, resulting in less than optimal battery capacity and therefore charge backup. Is it possible to predict how long, if I were to keep going about my business, the battery has before it completely runs out?

We have authorized Apple resellers only here so options to get the battery officially serviced are limited. Last year, the battery on my personal early 2015 MacBook Pro 13", with half the cycle count of the battery on this work machine, suddenly changed to "change battery" status from normal, and stopped giving me any backup. I had to get the battery replaced with a non-Apple/OEM battery which didn't cost much, but only gave a two-hour charge backup.

Comment: An indeterminate amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you use it and even there is no way of really knowing.